# PHP Retrieve Cookie which was not set with setcookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following problem - a third party software is setting a cookie with the login credentials and then forward the user to my app. I now need to retrieve the cookie values:

The problem is - I can do this easily in the Frontend/AS3 with

```
var ticket : String = CookieUtil.getCookie( 'ticket' ).toString();
```

but in PHP, the cookie is not within the $_COOKIES array.

The cookie values are:

```
Name: ticket
Domain: .myserver.com
Path : /
Send for: encrypted connections only
Expires: at end of session
```

The one I see, and set before in PHP, is:

```
Name: myCookie
Host: myserver.com
Path : /
Send for: any type of connection
Expires: at end of session
```

Actually, since host/domain are both the same, it should be visible in the PHP script, since it is running on this domain.

Any thoughts? Thankx

Martin

Comment: I just discovered: my connection between the frontend and the backend is running via HTTP and maybe this could be the reason why the first one, which gets only send for Secure Connections is invisible?
I will give it a shot, but I thought the secure stuff only applies to the URL in the browser and not to front/backend communication

Comment: what's the difference? what protocol do your front/backend communication use? FTP?

Comment: The frontend runs on a HTTPS (Flex) and it communicates with the backend in HTTP (only for login we use HTTPS)

Comment: And you are right. Cookie `ticket` has been set `for: encrypted connections only`. No wonder you can't get it for the insecure one

Answer (score 1):

Could this be domain sub domain issue? I mean www.myserver.com is not 'under' .www.myserver.com ... ?

The cookie should have the domain set to ".myserver.com"

Currently the only way to get this cookie is to have a script living under ".www.myserver.com" like "app.www.myserver.com"

EDIT: The OP had a typo. But are cookies with domain "myserver.com" members of ".myserver.com" ?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, that was a typo on my side. Edited my questions. It is of course .myserver.com and myserver.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can be useful for you but, the PHP manual [(cookie section)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) states:

Any **cookies sent to you from the client** will automatically be included into a 
$_COOKIE auto-global array **if variables_order  contains "C"**.

You should check the php config *variables_order* directive in order to be shure the Cookie flag is set.

Comment: that's incredible case. I have never seen a php installation with such a setting.

Comment: Me too, but if there is a tiny chance of a misconfigured installation, as the manual reports, maybe it is worth a deeper check

Answer (score 1):

ahahah got it! $_COOKIE not $_COOKIES :)

get a habit to program in PHP with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` reporting level, to avoid such a silly mistakes

Comment: How did you figure that out? You sitting next to him?

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts?

Actually, cookie is not a text file. But merely HTTP header.
So, to see a real cookie, one must watch HTTP interchange log, not the files on the client PC.
I am sure watching HTTP log would bring some light on the situation. It can be dome in many ways, LiveHTTPheaders mozilla addon for example.

Both `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` headers are to count.